# aes 256 strong password how many time to crack

Tags: encryption, time, passwords, aes

Is it true that this takes many years (even today) to crack an encryption with AES 256 with a strong password (of 17 characters and more)?

**example:**
 b&3,Gc9|N)#$*)Ùgé ?

Comment: How long something takes depends on how you're doing it.  How are you trying to "crack" this password?

Comment: Encryption passwords when used as password verifiers (for authentication) is not secure. Even saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 3):

A rough approximation:

Assuming 17 of the ~94 displayable ASCII characters that would be 94^17 potential passwords. The next question is how is the string converted to a 128-bit key?

If a good derivation method such as PBKDF2 with a sufficient iteration count to require ~100ms just multiply 94^16 * 100ms and convert to years: 10^24 years. Now divide by a faster decryptor than encryptor and the number of machines. Say 1,000  times faster and 1,000,000 machines and we are down to only 10^15 or 1,000,000,000,000,000 years.

Assuming no key derivation function and the same fast decryption devices and a decryption time on the encryption device of 25M/s still takes about 40,000,000 years.

Note: even using a 128-bit AES key a brute force attack will not be successful in a lifetime (even of the earth).

See: [lesser known details about the NSA's capabilities](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50527/4747) by poncho.